# Multiple choice list column visible everywhere

Tags: sharepoint-online, view-styles

I am using a custom multiple list  choice formatting in my Sharepoint list. Something has changed during last weekend, because now I can see formatted items not only in the general list view but also when editing the list entry. Before the items to choose from the multiple choice were visible as a plain text and visible as icon in the general list view. ( that is the formatting I am using - display text as the Icon). Now the icons are presented not only in the view, but also in the dropdown list.  Which is a problem for me. Does anyone know if there is an option to present formatted column in the view, but not when selecting items from the list?

Comment: Are you referring to JSON column formatting? Can't you just remove the current JSON , which I guess is causing the issue, with your original JSON and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I am reffering to Hson formatting. If I remove the JSON, it will work, but than I got a text instead an icons in List view.

Comment: You can post the column type and your JSON if possible for us to further troubleshoot. Have you tried the same on another column on another list to see if you get the same behavior?

Comment: This is happening because of some latest updates (column enhancements) by Microsoft in SharePoint online/Microsoft lists.